# Question about editing by multiple Models and one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

i have three Models(word,Adjectiv,Adverb) and one Controller(Words) that manage these Models.I have only one form,that user can add an adverb,an Adjectiv or a word.
My edit function:

```
def edit
        @word=Word.find(params[:id])
        @adjektiv=Adjektiv.find(params[:id])
        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end
```

for example when i want to edit one record of adverb (id=1) another records of adjectiv and Word with id=1 appear in Textboxes.I would like to be watched only the first record of adverb
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: don't you have in your form a way to know what is the user introducing (word, adjektiv or adverb?)?

Comment: I use Ajax accordion and each one(word,adjectiv,adverb) has own tab

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a perfect situation to use STI (Single Table Inheritance) since adjektives and adverbs are words too. To achive this you will need an string field called type in your words table. Then you could do it like this:

```
def Word < ActiveRecord::Base
end

def Adjektiv < Word
end

def Adverb < Word
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
def edit
  @word=Word.find(params[:id])   
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have not chosen the best name for my table.these table havn't any realation at all.would you please tell me,how can i solve this problem in  my Scnario?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one user form but multiple models, it means that you are associating multiple models with a single controller. Hence, it is advisable to go with a **nested-model-form** approach.

Please follow this [excellent railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) by Ryan Bates on Nest Form-Model.

The link is for part 1 of the railscast, you can find subsequent railscast in the same website.

This approach will make your code cleaner, more efficient and easier to maintain.

Thanks.